# React-Native Welcome Screen on first login

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, react-native

I am developing a React-Native app in which I want to include a Welcome Screen that shows up after the user logs in, but only on the first time. I have already developed the Welcome Screen with React-Native-App-Intro-Slider and it works fine, but it shows up every time the user opens the app.

This is the code I have at the moment. This is the Welcome.js code:

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, I18nManager, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';
import { TouchableRipple } from 'react-native-paper'
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'
import styles from './Welcome.styles';

I18nManager.forceRTL(false);

const slides = [
    {
        key: 'k1',
        title: '',
        text:
            '',
        video: {
            'id': 'k1',
            'name': '',
            'externalUrl': '',
            'link': '',
            'type': 'video',
            'uuid': 'external',
            'cover_url': '',
            'title-human': '',
            'brand-human': '',
        },
        image: require('../../assets/images/logo.png')
    },
    {
        key: 'k2',
        title: 'Step 1:',
        text: '',
        video: {
            'id': 'k2',
            'name': '',
            'externalUrl': '',
            'link': '',
            'type': 'video',
            'uuid': 'external',
            'cover_url': '',
            'title-human': '',
            'brand-human': '',
        },
        footer: ''
    },
    {
        key: 'k3',
        title: 'Step 2:',
        text: 'Connect your music through your speakers',
        video: {
            'id': 'k3',
            'name': '',
            'externalUrl': '',
            'link': '',
            'type': 'video',
            'uuid': 'external',
            'cover_url': '',
            'title-human': '',
            'brand-human': '',
        },
    }, {
        key: 'k4',
        title: '',
        text: '',
        video: {
            'id': 'k4',
            'name': '',
            'externalUrl': '',
            'link': '',
            'type': 'video',
            'uuid': 'external',
            'cover_url': '',
            'title-human': '',
            'brand-human': '',
        },
    },
    {
        key: 'k5',
        title: 'And lastly...',
        image: require('../../assets/images/logo.png'),
        text: '',
        footer: ''
    }

];

export default class Welcome extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show_Main_App: false
        }
    }

    static navigationOptions = { header: null }

    on_Done_all_slides = () => {
        this.setState({ show_Main_App: true });
    };


    on_Skip_slides = () => {
        this.setState({ show_Main_App: true });
    };

    _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.mainContent}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
            {item.image == undefined ? (
                <>
                    <View style={styles.videoContainer}>
                        <FastImage style={styles.videoImage} resizeMode='cover' source={{ uri: item.video.cover_url }} />
                        <View style={styles.videoDetailsContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.videoTagContainer}>
                                <Text style={styles.videoTagText}> </Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.featuredVideoButtonsContainer}>

                                <TouchableRipple
                                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'VideoPlayer', key: 'videoPlayer', params: { 'item': item.video } })}
                                    rippleColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, .32)'
                                >
                                    <View style={styles.videoPlayButton}>
                                        <Icon style={styles.videoPlayButtonIcon} name='play-circle' size={100} color='#fff' />
                                        <Text style={styles.videoPlayButtonText}>Play</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableRipple>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text}</Text>
                </>
            ) : (
                    <>
                        <Image source={item.image} style={styles.image} resizeMode='contain' />
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>
                                {item.text}
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>
                                {item.footer}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </>
                )}
        </View>
    );

    render() {
        if (this.state.show_Main_App) {
            return (
                this.props.navigation.replace('Dashboard')
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <AppIntroSlider
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                    slides={slides}
                    onDone={this.on_Done_all_slides}
                    showSkipButton={true}
                    onSkip={this.on_Skip_slides} />
            );
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, this works exactly as intended. However, it shows up every time. This is my App.js code:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { View, StatusBar, Text } from 'react-native'
// import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'
import IconFontawesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import IconMaterial from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
import { MenuProvider } from 'react-native-popup-menu';

// screens
import Splashscreen from './src/screens/Splashscreen/Splashscreen'
import ProfileSetup from './src/screens/ProfileSetup/ProfileSetup'
import UserCreation from './src/screens/UserCreation/UserCreation'
import Login from './src/screens/Login/Login'
import Signup from './src/screens/Signup/Signup'
import VideoPlayer from './src/screens/VideoPlayer/VideoPlayer'
import VideoProfile from './src/screens/VideoProfile/VideoProfile'
import AudioProfile from './src/screens/AudioProfile/AudioProfile'
import ForgotPassword from './src/screens/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword'
import Welcome from './src/screens/Welcome/Welcome'
import WhoWatching from './src/screens/WhoWatching/WhoWatching'

// Tabs
import MenuScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/MenuScreen/MenuScreen'
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/HomeScreen/HomeScreen'
// import DownloadScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/DownloadScreen/DownloadScreen' // avega : replaced with devices screen
import DeviceScreen from "./src/screens/TabScreens/DeviceScreen/DeviceScreen";
import SearchScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/SearchScreen/SearchScreen'

// Menu Screens
import AccountScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/MenuScreen/AccountScreen/AccountScreen'
import AppSettingsScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/MenuScreen/AppSettingsScreen/AppSettingsScreen'
import CellularDataUsageScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/MenuScreen/AppSettingsScreen/CellularDataUsageScreen/CellularDataUsageScreen'
import VideoQualityScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/MenuScreen/AppSettingsScreen/VideoQualityScreen/VideoQualityScreen'
import HelpScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/MenuScreen/HelpScreen/HelpScreen'
import ManageProfilesScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/MenuScreen/ManageProfilesScreen/ManageProfilesScreen'
import MyListScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/MenuScreen/MyListScreen/MyListScreen'
import PrivacyScreen from './src/screens/TabScreens/MenuScreen/PrivacyScreen/PrivacyScreen'
import configureStore from "./src/state/store";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {Root} from "native-base";
import DeviceProfile from "./src/screens/DeviceProfile/DeviceProfile";
import DeviceEnroll from "./src/screens/DeviceEnroll/DeviceEnroll";


const DashboardTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        HomeScreen: HomeScreen,
        SearchScreen: SearchScreen,
        DeviceScreen: DeviceScreen,
        MenuScreen: MenuScreen
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let iconName;

                if (routeName === 'MenuScreen') {
                    iconName = `menu`
                } else if (routeName === 'HomeScreen') {
                    iconName = `home`
                } else if (routeName === 'DeviceScreen') {
                    iconName = `television`;
                } else if (routeName === 'SearchScreen') {
                    iconName = `thermometer`
                }
                // return <IconFontawesome name={iconName} size={30} color={focused ? '#fff' : '#c0d3d6'} />
                return <IconMaterial name={iconName} size={30} color={focused ? '#fff' : '#c0d3d6'} />
            },
            tabBarLabel: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let labelName;
                if (routeName === 'MenuScreen') {
                    labelName = `Menu`
                } else if (routeName === 'HomeScreen') {
                    labelName = `Showcase`
                } else if (routeName === 'DeviceScreen') {
                    labelName = `Devices`
                } else if (routeName === 'SearchScreen') {
                    labelName = `Store`
                }
                return <Text style={focused ? { textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 11, color: '#fff', fontWeight: '600', marginTop: -5, marginBottom: 5 } : { textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 11, marginTop: -5, marginBottom: 5, color: '#C0D3D6' }}>{labelName}</Text>
            }
        }),
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#ff3402',
            inactiveTintColor: '#eaeaea',
            style: {
                backgroundColor: '#00A5AC',
                height: 65
            },
            labelStyle: {
                color: '#fff'
            }
        },
        initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    }
)

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Splashscreen: Splashscreen,
        UserCreation: UserCreation,
        Login: Login,
        Signup: Signup,
        ProfileSetup: ProfileSetup,
        Dashboard: DashboardTabNavigator,
        Account: AccountScreen,
        AppSettings: AppSettingsScreen,
        VideoQuality: VideoQualityScreen,
        CellularDataUsage: CellularDataUsageScreen,
        Help: HelpScreen,
        ManageProfiles: ManageProfilesScreen,
        MyList: MyListScreen,
        Privacy: PrivacyScreen,
        VideoPlayer: VideoPlayer,
        VideoProfile: VideoProfile,
        AudioProfile: AudioProfile,
        //AudioPlayer: AudioPlayer
        ForgotPassword: ForgotPassword,
        WhoWatching: WhoWatching,
        DeviceProfile: DeviceProfile,
        DeviceEnroll: DeviceEnroll,
        Welcome: Welcome
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Splashscreen',
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)

export default class App extends React.Component {
    store = configureStore();

    render () {

        return (
            <Provider store={this.store}>
                <Root>
                    <MenuProvider>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            <AppContainer />
                            <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor='transparent' barStyle='light-content' />
                        </View>
                    </MenuProvider>
                </Root>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see the first page is a Splashscreen, that then should lead to the guided tour. This is the Splashscreen.js code:

```
import { View, Image, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import styles from './Splashscreen.styles'
import AuthHelperMethods from "../../api/auth-helper-methods";
export default class Splashscreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = { header: null }
  componentDidMount () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      AuthHelperMethods.loggedIn().then((isLoggedIn) => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          this.props.navigation.replace('Welcome')
        } else {
          this.props.navigation.replace('UserCreation')
        }
      })
    }, 500)
  }
  state={ 
    loading: true
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.logo} resizeMode='contain' source={require('../../assets/images/logo.png')} />
        <ActivityIndicator size={50} color='#00b2ba' />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure how to start conceptualizing the idea of this component only showing up either on first-time login, or at least once per login instead of every time the app is used.

Any ideas how to go about it?

Comment: Every time 'Welcome' screen appears because you've added "show_Main_App" flag in state so every time when user comes to the screen, it has it's default state so it shows welcome screen. Way around is that you should persist "show_Main_App" flag either in Redux to persist or use AsyncStorage for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `localStorage`. You will have to do some conditional rendering. Whenever user launches the app, you will have to do something like `localStorage.setItem('firstTime', false)`. So, next time when user launches the app,  all you need is check if `localStorage.getItem('firstTime') === false`, if it is false, you render your **login page**.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably using `asyncStorage` (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

After installing it import it like:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

or

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'   //Deprecated, will be removed in the future
```

After you've showed the user the welcome screen, store the data inside `asyncStorage`:

```
storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('welcomeScreenSeen', 'true')
  } catch (e) {
    // saving failed
  }
}
```

After that, ever login would check that variable and if it's false, just skip your welcomeScreen.

then inside your isLoggedInIf it would be:

```
if (isLoggedIn) {
      this.props.navigation.replace(this.getData("welcomeScreenSeen")?'ScreenDifferentFromWelcome':'Welcome')
    }
```

where getData would be:

```
getData = async (key) => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
    return value
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences to check if it is the first login.

Simply store a `boolean` like `showWelcomeScreen` when the welcome screen was shown.
On startup you can check the  shared preferences and decide wheter to show or not to show the screen.

For more information check: [Shared Preferences](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shared-preferences)